# i want to delete an item from local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

actually i just want to grab the text inside the li elemets

Here is the html

```
    <ul id="list">
    <li class="list-item">dfsdf<button class="del-btn">delete</button></li>
    <li class="list-item">dfsd<button class="del-btn">delete</button></li>
     </ul>
```

so when i click on the first delete button i want to grab 'dfsdf' as string and when i click the the second delete button i want the value to be 'dfsd' as string

and e.target.parentElement.textContent gives dfsdfdelete and dfsddelete respectively when i click the first and the second button because of the button with text delete,
i want  e.target.parentElement.textContent = dfsdf 
and e.target.parentElement.textContent = dfsd respectively

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

to delete anything from localstorage add your key into next code.

```
localStorage.removeItem('keyName');
```

or

```
delete window.localStorage["keyName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`Text.prototype.wholeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) along with `HTMLElement.prototype.closest`:

```js
for (const delBtn of document.querySelectorAll('.del-btn')) {
  delBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const liText = this.closest('li').childNodes[0].wholeText;
    // alternative:
    // const liText = this.previousSibling.textContent;
    // or 
    // const liText = this.parentElement.childNodes[0].wholeText;
    // but those ones rely even more strictly on your current DOM structure
    console.log(liText);
  })
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="list-item">dfsdf<button class="del-btn">delete</button></li>
  <li class="list-item">dfsd<button class="del-btn">delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
localStorage.removeItem(tasks);
```

Or

```
localStorage.clear();
```